# check types passed to variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I would like to achieve something like that:

```
template<class... Args>
class MyClass{
  public:
    MyClass(){
      for(auto arg : {sizeof(Args)...})
        std::cout<<arg<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

But with one simple exception. The type char* should return 0(or everything else, what will be distinct from an int).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `sizeof(Args)...` -- tells me as if you are trying to print the size of the types?

Comment: I'd like to store sizes of passed types except char* (cause I won't be able to recognize if it was char* or int).

Comment: @MiniKarol: "cause I won't be able to recognize if it was char* or int" That would be true of *any* pointer type (and only on 32-bit compilers, or 64-bit ones that make `int` 64-bits in size). So why do you single out `char*`?

Comment: You are right. But I will have to handle with only several uint types (8,16,32,64) and char*.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
/* heavily borrowed from IBM's variadic template page */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
template<typename T> struct type_size{
    operator int(){return sizeof( T );}
};

template<> struct type_size <char *>{
    operator int(){return 0;}
};
*/
/* as per Mattieu M.'s suggestion */
template<typename T> constexpr size_t type_size(T dummy) {
return sizeof dummy;
}

constexpr size_t type_size(char *){
    return 0;
} 
template <typename...I> struct container{
    container(){
    int array[sizeof...(I)]={type_size<I>()...};
    printf("container<");
    for(int count = 0; count<sizeof...(I); count++){
        if(count>0){
            printf(",");
        }
        printf("%d", array[count]);
    }
    printf(">\n");
    }
};

int main(void){
   container<int, short, char *> g;
}
```

Comment: This should print something like: `container<4,2,0>`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Are you referring to the `for`-loop? I tried to keep the code as close as possibe to the OP's code. Evidently, I didn't pass muster :/

Comment: No, I was talking about using types with `operator()`. They could be `constexpr` and even `constexpr` functions.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: +1! Oh, yes! :) Need a reminder these days about what can and what can't be done with `constexpr` :P

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
std::size_t size()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

template<>
std::size_t size<char*>()
{
    return 0;
}

template<class... Args>
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        std::initializer_list<char> { (std::cout << size<Args>(), void(), char {})... };
    }
};
```

Although in truth I have an `EXPAND` macro that hides the `std::initializer_list` ugliness (not to mention `void()` + comma operator trick) such that it would look like `EXPAND( std::cout << size<Args>() )`.